# displaying retrieved images in dynamically created image tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, src

I can set src of `<img />` tag by Src attribute in codebehind, after retrieving image data from database like this:

html:

```
<img runat="server" id="photo" alt="" src=""/>
```

codebehind:

```
byte[] b = null;
//db connection here          
            while (sdr.Read())
            {

                Room room = new Room();
                b = (byte[])sdr["photo"];
                picture.Src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(b).ToString();

            }
```

I cannot apply the same for dynamically created img html controls: because Src property doesn't recognize it (in build time).

```
Room r=new Room();
 b = (byte[])sdr["Photo"];
 r.Photo.Src= "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(b).ToString();
```

(r.Photo.Src --> Error here:'string' doesn't contain a definition for 'Src' and no extension method 'Src' accepting a first argument of type string could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?))

part of my jquery code:

```
$.each(r, function (k) {
         divItem.append(
                     $('<div />', { "class": "row" }).append($('<img />', { "class": "h-looks" ,"id":"photo"})),
                     $('<span />', { "class": "hiddenidspan",text:id })
                       );
                });
```

Dynamically created img tags are not runat="server", but either way they don't exist in build time.

How can I do this?

Comment: How do you create those 'Dynamically created img tags'?

Comment: I don't see any dynamically created `<img>` in your code. You're accessing a `Room` object `Picture` property (which is a string) and I guess `Room` is your database object (or view model or whatever) but not an UI control. If it's what returned to client then simply write string in `Photo` property, it has not a `src` property (that it will be done client side)

Comment: To add the `src` attribute to an HTML element you need to use `r.Photo.Attributes.Add("src", "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(b).ToString());`

Comment: They are created in JQuery code. Why downvote?

Comment: @linda22 why cant you use the `runat="server"` in your jquery creation of dynamic controls

Comment: @Webruster ASP.NET doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the base64 string on server and store them as js array. Then in js, when you create the image, just use appropriate line from pre-generated array.